# Trying to implement collision detection between two sprites - libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision, detection

Bit of background about the current game: **Player** is always moving from left to right, if the screen is tapped he jumps if it's dragged he dashes forward. I added a tile (**Platform** object) and am now trying to make my **Player** stop moving if he hits it.

The **Player** starts on the bottom left of the screen, and the **Platform** is on the top right. What happens is that the **Player** stops when he reaches the middle of the screen, rather than the actual Platform. Can anyone have a look at my code and see if they can figure out why? Would be highly appreciated.

```
public class Platform extends GameObject 
{
    private Rectangle playerRect;
    private Rectangle platformRect;
    private Player player;
    private boolean isOverlapping;

    public Platform(Sprite spr) 
    {
        super(spr);
        player = Player.getInstance(null); // Initialises the Player class (a Singleton)

        // Set position of sprite
        setxPos(getWidth() - 400);
        setyPos(getHeight() / 2 - 100);
        spr.setX(getxPos()); 
        spr.setY(getyPos());         
    }

    public void update() 
    {
        // Rectangle of Player
        playerRect = new Rectangle(player.getxPos(), player.getyPos(), player
            .getSprite().getWidth() + player.getxPos(), player.getSprite()
            .getHeight() + player.getyPos());

        // Rectangle of Platform
        platformRect = new Rectangle(getxPos(), getyPos(), getSprite().getWidth()
            + getxPos(), getSprite().getHeight() + getxPos());

        // Make Player stop moving if the two rectangles collide
        isOverlapping = playerRect.overlaps(platformRect);

        if (isOverlapping) 
        {
            player.setxSpeed(0);            
        }
    }
}
```

Have been stuck on this for a while, thanks in advance for any input

Comment: possible duplicate of [libGDX - Trying to implement collision between 2 sprites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091077/libgdx-trying-to-implement-collision-between-2-sprites)